# CW complex is connected iff 1-skeleton is connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be CW-complex and by $X^n$ I denote its n-skeleton. Here is my attempt to prove that connectedness of $X$ and $X^1$ are equivalent.

First, assume that $X^1$ is not connected, which means one can represent $X^1$ as disjoint union of two closed subcomplexes. Let $X^n$ be not connected. We prove by induction that $X^{n+1}$ is not connected. Indeed, consider $X^n$ with $(n+1)$-cell attached. If one assumes that this space is connected, than he would consider the boundary of the cell attached, which is contained in $X^n$ by $C$-axiom of CW-complex. The boundary contains cells from both of disjoint components (because otherwise connectedness of the n-skeleton with cell attached would be violated), which contradicts with its connectedness. Thus, each $X^n$ is not connected and then $X$ also is.

Now let $X^1$ be connected. If one of $X^n$'s is not connected, then it can be represented as disjoint union of two subcomplexes, whose 1-skeletons (their union is $X^1$) are disjoint and closed; contradiction.

Comment: For your last sentence, how do you know the connected components are subcomplexes?

Comment: @cheerfulparsnip That is because connected components are closed and every closed subset of CW-complex is subcomplex due to weak topology on the complex.

Comment: @igortsts closed subsets need not be subcomplexes. They don't even have to be cw complexes at all. They don't even have to have the homotopy type of a cw complex. Consider the Cantor set. It is compact (hence closed in $\mathbb{R}$) but has infinitely many connected components, therefore it is not a cw complex. It can even be shown that it doesn't have the homotopy type of a cw complex.

Comment: @freakish oh, my bad! of course, subcomplex is closed subspace _which is union of cells_. These disjoint closed components of $X$ are unions of cells and hence subcomplexes

Comment: @igortsts Well, that's what you claim and it probably is true. But I don't see it yet. :D

Comment: Every cell is connected (image of $D^n$), so each cell sits inside a single connected component. That should be enough to see that connected components are subcomplexes.